# Sending email in my app without using third party apps

Tags: android, email

I need to send an email from my app, I've an EditBox and a send button in a DialogFragment. Doing this I get a popup to select an email app. I want to send the email at background without using any apps just the send button.
Here is the code:

*****EDIT*****
I just wanna send an email so I've created this app:
Just a EditText and a button, I've the libraries activation, adittional and mail working fine but when I send the mail the app throws an exception:

javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465, response: -1

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
private Button enviar;
private String correo, pass;
private EditText frase;
private Session session;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    enviar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enviar_button);
    frase = findViewById(R.id.frase_id);

    correo="myEmail@gmail.com";
    pass="myPass";


    enviar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy=new  StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("mail.smtp.host","smtp.gmail.com");
            properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port","465");
            properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","java.net.SSLSocketFactory");
            properties.put("mail.smtp.auth","true");
            properties.put("mail.smtp.port","465");

            try{
                session= Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, new Authenticator() {
                    @Override
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(correo,pass);
                    }
                });

                if(session!=null){
                    Message message= new MimeMessage(session);
                    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(correo));
                    message.setSubject("SUBJECT");
                    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse("destinationMail@gmail.com"));
                    message.setContent(frase.getText().toString(),"text/html; charset=utf-8");
                    Transport.send(message);
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: did you try `javax.mail`? im actually not sure if its available on Android...

Comment: https://github.com/ErNaveen/GmailSendInBackground

Comment: javax.mail is not working anymore.

Comment: Hey Naveen is a tutorial or anything? than you.

Answer (score 2):

it is possible to send email in background use following code, to send email

```
public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator 
{   
private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";   
private String user;   
private String password;   
private Session session;   
private Multipart _multipart;

static 
{   
    Security.addProvider(new JSSEProvider());   
}  

public GMailSender(String user, String password) 
{   
    this.user = user;   
    this.password = password;   

    Properties props = new Properties();   
    props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");   
    props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);   
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");   
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");   
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");   
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");   
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");   
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");   

    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);
    _multipart = new MimeMultipart();
}   

protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() 
{   
    return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);   
}   

public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception 
{   
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);   
    DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));   
    message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));   
    message.setSubject(subject);   

    message.setDataHandler(handler);   
    message.setContent(_multipart);
    if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)   
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));   
    else  
        message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));   
    Transport.send(message);   

}   

public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception 
{
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);

    _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
}

public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource 
{   
    private byte[] data;   
    private String type;   

    public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) 
    {   
        super();   
        this.data = data;   
        this.type = type;   
    }   

    public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) 
    {   
        super();   
        this.data = data;   
    }   

    public void setType(String type) 
    {   
        this.type = type;   
    }   

    public String getContentType() 
    {   
        if (type == null)   
            return "application/octet-stream";   
        else  
            return type;   
    }   

    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException 
    {   
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);   
    }   

    public String getName() 
    {   
        return "ByteArrayDataSource";   
    }   

    public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException 
    {   
        throw new IOException("Not Supported");   
    }   
}   
}
```

and

```
public final class JSSEProvider extends Provider 
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public JSSEProvider() 
{
    super("HarmonyJSSE", 1.0, "Harmony JSSE Provider");
    AccessController.doPrivileged(new java.security.PrivilegedAction<Void>() 
    {
        public Void run() 
        {
            put("SSLContext.TLS",
                    "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLContextImpl");
            put("Alg.Alias.SSLContext.TLSv1", "TLS");
            put("KeyManagerFactory.X509",
                    "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.KeyManagerFactoryImpl");
            put("TrustManagerFactory.X509",
                    "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerFactoryImpl");
            return null;
        }
    });
}
}
```

You would be requiring activation.jar, additionnal.jar & mail.jar files

download jar files from here  https://code.google.com/archive/p/javamail-android/downloads

Comment: but android studio is not recognizing Javax.mail

Comment: @HectorChamorroAlvarez you need to add this libraries to your project: https://code.google.com/archive/p/javamail-android/downloads

Comment: in which class?

Comment: in the JSSEProvider class